# [Android]: prevent USB device from sleeping when Android device sleeps

Tags: android, networking, usb, lan

We are making a SIP-related solution and I am requested to compose an app on a customized android pad(4.4.*). Unluckily, the pad is from 3rd party and accordingly we hardly do further jobs on the framework or driver......
On the Pad, a LAN port is designed over USB and we plan to access network via LAN. Besides, no power key is populated on the cover.....

Now the question is: Since the pad sleeps, the LAN connection is stopped soon. I fully understand it's a normal behavior that android conducts. I am trying to acquire known wake lock(partial or WIFI lock) to stop USB controller from sleeping ... but, currently, little progress. is there any usb-related  wake lock, just like wifi lock ?

Comment: Also  ,Can I call some API in C and interact with display driver ???

Comment: I suggest breaking the question into 2 questions

Comment: @ Mahendra Gunawardena.  Thanks for the suggestion ...I try to figure the question out  by breaking ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem from the perspective of HW .... I am not sure the solution is really meaningful to the current topic. But I think that sharing the idea with you is the major goal of the forum running.

a MOS component is added along the power line controlling Screen. Then I manipulate the connection/disconnection by sending command to MCU....

Based on my experiences , it is really hard to extend functionality on a poor quality of pad ... poor post-sales support.......

Hope you it's helpful to you.